# SQL server database copy data and update one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, copy

I have an existing table [dba.Text] and all the data in the table has to stay in there, the only thing I want is to copy all data with the year 2017 and change it to 2018. I tried to make it in Excel to show what I mean:

[image: How the table should look like]

Hope someone can lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you know SQL?   This is really really really simple.

Comment: Most people in here would like to see data in formatted text, tag Database you are using . Also have u researched a bit about `Insert/update` in google

Comment: It's acutally long time ago i've worked with sql, so i just wanted to be sure. I know it's really simple nothing there, just wanted to make it right

Answer (score 1):

If I got this right I think you need something like this (I assume that `PageId` is auto-increment)

```
INSERT INTO <your_table>
SELECT
    Key
    ,Value
    ,2018
FROM <your_table>
WHERE Year = 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider we have table like below

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
        [year] [int] NULL,
        [MedTitle] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [FullTitle] [varchar](50) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

---insert values for the table 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]
           ([year]
           ,[MedTitle]
           ,[FullTitle])
     VALUES
           (<year, int,>
           ,<MedTitle, varchar(50),>
           ,<FullTitle, varchar(50),>)
GO
```

Table content:

```
    year    MedTitle    FullTitle
    2017    1   This is first
    2017    2   This is first
    2017    3   This is first
```

Then:

```
    Declare @year  int,
    @MedTitle varchar(50),
    @FullTitle varchar(50)

    Declare AIX Cursor
           for Select year, MedTitle, FullTitle
            from [dbo].[Test] where year=2017
    Open AIX;
        Fetch Next from AIX into @year,@MedTitle,@FullTitle;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    --set @aixrowid = (select MAX(aixrowid)+1 from [dbo].[Test])

    insert [dbo].[test] (year, MedTitle, FullTitle)
        values  (2018,@MedTitle,@FullTitle)
    FETCH NEXT FROM AIX 
        INTO  @year, @MedTitle,@FullTitle;
    END
    CLOSE AIX;
    DEALLOCATE AIX;
```

Finally

```
    Select * from dbo.text
```

With result:

```
    year    MedTitle    FullTitle
    2017    1   This is first
    2017    2   This is first
    2017    3   This is first
    2018    1   This is first
    2018    2   This is first
    2018    3   This is first
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping guys, i figured out how to update the year. I tried with the following statement

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEST]
       ([PageID]
       ,[Key]
       ,[Value]
       ,[Year])

       (SELECT [PageID]
  ,[Key]
  ,[Value], '2018' 
FROM [database name].[dbo].[TEST] 
where Year = '2017'
)
```